# Android App No Longer Displaying Ads from AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I'm not sure when it first happened, but the free version of my app no longer displays ads.  In LogCat I see the following:

No fill from ad server.
Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now
Failed to load ad: 3
Ad is not visible. Not refreshing Ad

Here's my code (executes w/o throwing exception):

```
        // Create an ad             
        adView = (AdView) context.findViewById(R.id.adView);    

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("C159C2E9AAFBF1EF1788369DDBFCD344") 
            .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you have installed Google Play Services and implemented it in your gradle correctly. If problem still persists, check your account on AdMob and see if there is anything wrong.

Comment: I'll check, but this was working before. Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't be using `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)` to your release. Check also if your Admob id is correct.

Comment: 1.  New device requires new test device id - this issue resolved. 2. Running in emulator - ads still work.  3.  According to what I read I can leave the addTestDevice statements in place as they will only be effective in those two test environments. 4. I did check my account with AdMob, finally, and apparently I never entered my PIN to confirm my address.  I've requested a new PIN.  Could this be why ads are no longer working in release builds?  Thanks for everyone's help so far.

Comment: When I log into AdMob, I see the message "Your ad units are not displaying ads because you haven't verified your PIN".  Guess I'll wait for PIN to arrive.

Comment: PIN arrived, PIN submitted.  Ads are now working in released version even with the two AddTestDevice statements in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal response.
From time to time a device may not have an ad available, in which case your will receive 'No fill from ad server".

The best mitigation is to use mediation to iterate over a number of ad networks in case of no fill.

Comment: That's good advice, but I don't think that's my issue.  Thank you.

Comment: If the response from the AdServer is 'No fill from ad server' then it is **exactly** your issue.

Comment: Perhaps that would be my issue if I had submitted my PIN to AdMob. But that simple step enabled ads to start working.  Thanks for your help.